# jquery.html() strange behavior with form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following html:

```
<div class="copy_me_text">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="copy_me_hidden">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="name" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And following js code:

```
var $cloned_text = $('.copy_me_text').clone();
$cloned_text.find('input[name="name"]').val("SOMETHING");
$cloned_text.find('input[name="id"]').val("SOMETHING");
console.log($cloned_text.html());

var $cloned_hidden = $('.copy_me_hidden').clone();
$cloned_hidden.find('input[name="name"]').val("SOMETHING");
$cloned_hidden.find('input[name="id"]').val("SOMETHING");
console.log($cloned_hidden.html());
```

And output is strange for me:

```
<div>
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <input value="SOMETHING" name="id" type="hidden">
</div>
<div>
    <input value="SOMETHING" name="name" type="hidden">
    <input value="SOMETHING" name="id" type="hidden">
</div>
```

I create also jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xRjPm/1/).
Is it correct behavior? I don't understand, why in `.html()` function, value of `input type="text"` is not returned.

Comment: isolated behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/xRjPm/4/

Comment: @jbabey: it is different since you're cloning an element with id, duplicate ids can produce unexpected behavior as expected.

Comment: @SalmanA the clone is never added to the DOM, and the duplicate IDs do not exist in the same container we're using as a context, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a strange jQuery behavior, its a strange DOM effect. [`jQuery.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) does nothing else than setting the `value` property of `<input>` element. By "property", I mean the DOM *property* and not the node *attribute* - see [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) for the difference.

The [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method, which returns the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) serialisation of the DOM, is expected to show only attributes of the elements - their properties are irrelevant. This is the default behaviour, and when you want input values serialized you need to explicitly set them as attributes - `$input.attr("value", $input.prop("value"))`.

So why did simple `val()` work on the hidden input elements? The reason is the HTML specification. There are [reflecting IDL attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#reflecting-content-attributes-in-idl-attributes), where the DOM property is coupled with the node attribute, but the `value` attribute is none of those. Yet, the [value IDL attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-value) has special modes, in which it reacts differently. To cite the spec:

> The attribute is in one of the following modes, which define its behavior:
>
> **value**
>
> > On getting, it must return the [current value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-value) of the element. On setting, it must set the [element's value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-value) to the new value, set the element's dirty value [… and do a  lot of other stuff].
>
> **default**
>
> > On getting, if the element has a [value attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value), it must return that attribute's value; otherwise, it must return the empty string. On setting, it must set the element's [value attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) to the new value.
>
> ["default/on" and "filename" modes]

Spot the difference? And now, let's have a look at the [states](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#states-of-the-type-attribute) of the [type attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-type). And really, if we check the *Bookkeeping details* sections, we can notice that in the [`hidden` state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#hidden-state-(type=hidden)),

> The `value` IDL attribute applies to this element and is in mode **default**

‐ while in all other (textual) states the mode is "value".

---

### TL;DR:

(Only) On `<input type="hidden">` elements, setting the `value` DOM property (`input.value = …`, `$input.val(…)`, `$input.prop("value", …)`) also sets the `value` attribute and makes it serializable for `innerHTML`/`.html()`.

Answer (score 6):

That certainly looks like a bug in jQuery. You can force it to return by using the `attr()` function:

```
$cloned_text.find('input[name="name"]').attr('value', "SOMETHING");
```

See the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xRjPm/2/)

Comment: The solution is right, but it's worth noting that it's not due to a jQuery bug. Please see my answer.

Comment: It's not a jQuery bug, it rather is unexpected behaviour of the DOM - see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `html()` function will return the html assign to the element. In your case you are assigning value to input text field.

Try this

```
$cloned_text.find('input[name="name"]').attr('value', "SOMETHING");
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a jQuery bug.

As you can see in [jQuery source code for the `val` method](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L220), they're just setting the `value` of the `input` element, which is a different thing from adding a new attribute to the element (which at the end, results in the `value` property change).

jQuery source (`hooks` is null in this context):

```
if ( !hooks || !("set" in hooks) || hooks.set( this, val, "value" ) === undefined ) {
    this.value = val;
}
```

So, to get what you what, you have to add a new `val` attribute to the element, using

```
.attr('value', "SOMETHING");
```

as others mentioned.

By using `.attr` the new attribute will be added to the element, and `.html` will return that as string.

Comment: @Kasyx: See my (lengthy) answer for that

Answer (score 1):

A good workaround for this problem would be to use the `attr()` function instead of the `val()`.

So, instead of

```
$cloned_text.find('input[name="name"]').val("SOMETHING");
```

Write

```
$cloned_text.find('input[name="name"]').attr("value", "SOMETHING");
```